# Generic and method

Tags: java

Why do I have to do like this?

```
public <T> void myMethod(MyClass<T> value){

}
```

Why do I have to mention `<T>` twice?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14107807/34397

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `<T>` declares your method as having a generic parameter.

The second `<T>` specified the value of the generic parameter for the `MyClass<>` class. (just like `MyClass<string>`)

Answer (score 1):

the first `<T>` declares that you are using a templated method.  It is just as proper to say the following:

```
public void myMethod(MyClass<?> value){

}
```

You can also declare the  generic parameter on the class level like so:

```
public class MyClass<T> {

    public void myMethod(MyClass<T> value){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The outer <T> says 'this is a generic method' and also gives you the chance to place bounds on T, for example T extends Comparable<T>. You wouldn't want to be repeating all that for every parameter that used T.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the first  defines that there is a generic class been used in your function and the second  `MyClass<T>` value says that the generic type of your class it `T` like in `List<String>` where `String` can be your `T`.